# Jquery click on icon doesn't work when icon moved inside password_field [Rails]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have implemented Show/Hide Password and Real time Password Validator for the login page on my client Rails app.
Everything works perfectly fine when this icon is outside of the input password field, however when i moved inside field (where it should be), cursor: pointer is disabled and I can no longer Show/Hide Password.

I have tried different thing in CSS without success.

Here is my code:

new.html.erb

```
          <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="user_login"><%= t('users.sign_in.email') %></label>
        <%= f.text_field :login, :class => "form-control overable", :placeholder => t('users.sign_in.email'), :autocomplete => "off" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group password">
        <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash fa-2x field-icon toggle-password" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <label for="exampleInputPassword" class="sr-only" name="password"></label>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control password", :id => "exampleInputPassword", :type => "password"  %>
      </div>
      <div id="validator-output">
      </div>
```

.css

```
/* // eye icon (password field) */
.password {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
}

.password .fa-eye-slash::before {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 45%;
    /* right: 30px; */
    right: -40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* pointer doesn't show if icon inside input? */
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.password .fa-eye::before {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 45%;
    /* right: 30px; */
    right: -40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* pointer doesn't show if icon inside input? */
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#validator-output {
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#validator-output .valid {
    color: green;
  }
#validator-output .invalid {
    color: red;
}
```

.js

```
//// Show/Hide Password
 $('body').on('click', '.toggle-password', function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash');
   var input = $('#exampleInputPassword');
   if (input.attr('type') === 'password') {
     input.attr('type', 'text');
   } else {
     input.attr('type', 'password');
   }
 });

//// Real time Password Validator
$(function () {
  $('#validator-output').realtimePasswordValidator({
    debug: true,
    input1: $('#exampleInputPassword'),
    validators: [
      {
        regexp: '.{10,}',
        message: 'Minimum 10 Characters',
      },
      {
        regexp: '[a-z]',
        message: '1 lowercase',
      },
      {
        regexp: '[A-Z]',
        message: '1 uppercase',
      },
      {
        regexp: '[0-9]',
        message: '1 number',
      },
      {
        regexp: '.*[!@#$%?=*&]',
        message: '1 special char !@#$%?=*&',
      },
    ],
    ok: function (instance) {
      console.log('ok');

      $('#login-submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    },
    ko: function (instance) {
      console.log('ko');
      $('#login-submit-btn').attr('disabled', '');
    },
  });
});

// plugin definition
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  var pluginName = 'realtimePasswordValidator',
    defaults = {
      debug: false,
    };
  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    init: function () {
      this.settings.input1.on('input', { self: this }, this.validateEvent);
    },

    validateEvent: function (event) {
      const self = event.data.self;
      const messages = [];
      let valid_count = 0;
      $(self.element).empty();
      $(self.settings.validators).each(function (index, validator) {
        let valid = false;
        if (validator.regexp)
          valid = new RegExp(validator.regexp).test(self.settings.input1.val());
        // if (validator.compare)
        //   valid = self.settings.input1.val() == $(self.settings.input2).val();
        const message = $('<div>' + validator.message + '</div>');
        message.addClass(valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
        if (self.settings.input1.val().length > 0)
          $(self.element).append(message);
        if (valid) valid_count++;
        if (this.debug)
          console.log(
            index,
            self.settings.input1.val(),
            validator.message,
            valid
          );
      });
      if (valid_count == self.settings.validators.length) {
        if (self.settings.ok) self.settings.ok(self);
      } else {
        if (self.settings.ko) self.settings.ko(self);
      }
      if (this.debug)
        console.log(
          'valid',
          valid_count,
          'of',
          self.settings.validators.length
        );
    },
  });

  $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Any help to fix that issue would be highly appreciated

Thank all

Comment: give z-index as 999 for that eye element

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the pointer is disabled leads me to think that another element is in front of it, for example the input itself, if it has a transparent background.

If that’s the case, you can use the `z-index` attribute in CSS to place the icon over the field.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your prompt reply.
It's indeed works with z-index attribute in CSS